# Creating a Relation in __init__ of a model (in Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, entity-relationship

Lets assume I had the following Model

```
class A(Models.model):
   def __init__(self,data):
      B(a=self,data=data).save()

class B(Models.model):
   data = somefieldtype
   a = Models.models.ForeignKey('A')
```

now as you might suspect, there is an error in this Model definintion, as one cannot create a relation to the A instance before ainstance.save() has been called. However, this type of init method would make my controllers much simpler. Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this code in an overridden `save` method of `A`:

```
def save(self,**kwargs):
   super(A,self).save(**kwargs)
   B(a=self,data=data).save()
```